# phpStorm can't find certificate for Wordpress SVN

Tags: wordpress, svn, certificate, phpstorm

I recently had my first plugin approved for wordpress repository, I have my empty repository at svn.wordpress.org, but every time I try to commit from PHPStorm, it asks me to browse to the certificate and to enter the passphrase. I have searched for a few hours and have not found anything. Has any one else succesffuly got phpstorm to commit files to the wordpress SVN repository?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Yes I did actually. I totally forgot that I had posted here. Will correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks, figured this out a while back, but forgot I had posted here.

So what was happening is this: I was using my display name as my login for the SVN repository. On the WP.org site I always used my email(can also use login name), but the svn would use my actual login, well I did not realize that my login was different from my display name, had forgotten that I had changed the display name years ago and just grabbed it real quick.